# Waving artifacts on texture/light Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, artifacts

In the image below there is a pattern on the material that was not intended. How do I fix this?

I attached image and .blend file. If You need any details, please, ask. I don't know what should I give more.

Could someone be as good and maybe generally correct this blend file? ;-) (nodes, lighting)

[image: Image description]

**[Blend file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103322369/Forum%20Blender/Namiot_0.95.blend)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your blend file and it seems like its the geometry of your object. Your getting these "wavy artifacts" because your shading is set to flat which is showing geometry thus creating this. So to get rid of them I would change the topology of your object.